# Conversation History not showing in Skype For Business Online

Tags: exchange-2010, skype-for-business-online

We've been working on this for a number of weeks now and are really struggling to find anymore potential solutions.

The issue is, **we're not seeing the conversation history or missed conversations in the Skype for Business application**. We are, however, receiving the conversation history in Outlook and that seems to be working fine. We can see user availability in Outlook and S4B is putting users as DnD when they're in a meeting so that all seems to be working fine.

We're using Exchange Server 2010 on premise and Skype for Business Online.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated, we're pulling our hair out over this!

Comment: Check the EWS link by right-clicking Skype for Business client and open Configuration Information, browser this link in IE and check the result.
BTW, how many users experience this issue?

Comment: Currently saying EWS Not Deployed. This is definitely believed to be the issue however we do not know how to rectify it. And it seems to be all of our users. We're currently testing with around 5-10 users before we roll it out to everybody.